# Why is my background color bleeding through to the front of my HTML table?

Tags: html, css

Am creating a table in HTML with a particular shape, and it works except for two cells, the top and the bottom, that somehow have a minute space between each other in which the background color bleeds through.

[background color bleed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mdvK.png)

If I delete any of the CSS elements for input, or not set a radius for the top and bottom cells there is no bleed.  But then I don't get the shape I wanted to create.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      padding-top: 10px;
      background: #660000;
    }
    
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body {
      font: 16px Arial;
    }
    
    input {
      border: 1px solid;
      padding: 5px;
      font-size: 24px;
    }
    
    input[type=text] {
      border: 1px solid;
      padding: 5px;
      font-size: 24px;
      border-color: #808080;
      background-color: #fff;
      width: 100%;
      -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    
    input[type=submit] {
      margin-left: 5px;
      padding: 5px;
      background: #ccc;
      cursor: pointer;
      -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
      border: 0px solid;
      background-color: #0000ff;
      border-color: #CCCCCC;
      color: #fff;
    }
    
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border: 0px;
    }
    
    table td#LISTROWHEAD {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      background-color: white;
      color: black;
      width: 300px;
      padding: 5px;
      font-size: 24px;
      border-top-left-radius: 6px;
      border-top-left-radius: 6px;
      border-top-right-radius: 6px;
      border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    }
    
    table td#LISTROWBUTT {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      background-color: white;
      color: black;
      padding: 5px;
      font-size: 24px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    }
    
    table td#LISTROW {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      background-color: white;
      color: black;
      padding: 5px;
      font-size: 24px;
    }
    
    h2 {
      font: 32px Arial;
      color: #333333;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body onload="setFocusToInput();">



  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="myBanner" type="static" placeholder="">
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <form autocomplete="off" action="/cgi-bin/prl.pl">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <!--Make sure the form has the autocomplete function switched off:-->
          <!--        <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;"> -->
          <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;"><input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Pick a title..." autofocus></div>
          <!--        </div> -->
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="113" type="submit" value="submit">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <table>

        <table>
          <tr>
            <td id="LISTROWHEAD">
              &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="LISTROW">
              &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="LISTROW">
              &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="LISTROW">
              &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="LISTROW">
              &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="LISTROW">
              &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="LISTROW">
              &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="LISTROW">
              Hello
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="LISTROW">
              &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="LISTROWBUTT">
              &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </form>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just on a note, please have a read about the use of [ID's in HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp) and please note they must be _unique_. You have `<td id="LISTROW" >` declared multiple times, which renders illegal HTML and may cause unexpected outputs. Consider changing this to a [HTML Class](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_classes.asp)

Comment: Because you have given each td CSS background color. First, remove that all background colors and give background to the table.

Comment: And can you change the snippet so that it actually demonstrates the problem? Currently it only shows the word Hello without the coloured lines from your screenshot.

Comment: @MrLister Yes, but by giving the table the background color, the radiuses disappear from the top and bottom cells.  I will make a shortened version of the code to run as here as a clip.